Show that the reflexive, symmetric, transitive closure of $R$ is the smallest equivalence relation containing $R$?
I've been given these definitions:



And there is this  exercise:



I tried to do what they suggest:
Let $R_e$ be an arbitrary equivalence relation generated by $R$:

Reflexivity: If $(a,b)\in R$, then $(a,a)$ and $(b,b)$ are elements of $R_r$, these elements aren't lost when we go from $R_r$ to $(R_r)_s$ to $((R_r)_s)_t$ and then: $((R_r)_s)_t$ is reflexive and $(a,a)\in ((R_r)_s)_t$ and $(a,a)\in R_e$ for all $a$.

Symmetry: If $(a,b)\in R$, then $(a,b)\in R_r$ and $(b,a)\in (R_r)_s$, these elements aren't lost when we go from $(R_r)_s$ to $((R_r)_s)_t$ and then: $((R_r)_s)_t$ Is symmetric and $(a,b),(b,a) \in ((R_r)_s)_t$ and $(a,b),(b,a)\in R_e$ for all $(a,b)$.

Transitivity: If $(a,b),(b,c)\in R$, then $(a,b),(b,c)\in R_r$ and $(a,b),(b,c)\in (R_r)_s$, these elements aren't lost when we go from $(R_r)_s$ to $((R_r)_s)_t$ and then: $((R_r)_s)_t$ is transitive and $(a,b),(b,c),(a,c)\in ((R_r)_s)_t$ and $(a,b),(b,c),(a,c)\in R_e$.


And hence, we have that $((R_r)_s)_t\subset R_e$.
Disclaimer: I actually wrote a bit more to explain this "the elements aren't lost" by actually  checking what we add when we go from one closure to the other.
Is this demonstration correct this way?

This is hard to follow.  What exactly are you trying to prove in each case?  I suggest beginning each of your sections with a clear statement of your goal.

I subscribe @lulu's comment. And let be add a few observations (maybe more would be relevant). To prove that $((R_r)_s)_t \subseteq R_e$, you don't pick an element from $R$ and show it is in $R_e$, as that would only show that $R  \subseteq R_e$. Also, for example in the reflexivity paragraph, you start with "If $(a,b) \in R$ then $(a,a)$ and $(b,b)$ are elements of $R_r$". This is true but it is an understatement, because it could be that for some $a \in X$, there is no $b$ such that either $(a,b) \in R$ or $(b,a) \in R$, but $(a,a)\in R_r$ for all $a \in X$. There are other similar problems.

@lulu I am trying to keep track of what happens when we go from $R$ to $R_r$ to $(R_r)_s$ to $((R_r)_s)_t$. Not only we add the desired elements but when we go from one step to the other, the elements added in the previous step aren't removed. Also, when we get to the last step, all the elements will be kept and hence $((R_r)_s)_t$ will be an equivalence relation and every element in $((R_r)_s)_t$ will be an element of any $R_e$ so $((R_r)_s)_t\subset R_e$.

@amrsa I'm picking an element of $R$, seeing what happens when we go from $R$, then to $R_r$, then to $(R_r)_s$, then to $((R_r)_s)_t$. Checking that they aren't lost from one step to the other and noticing that the elements that are generated in each step must be in any $R_e$.

Again,  clarity is vital.  Edit your argument to include clear,  step by step indications of what precise statement you are proving at any moment.  You are writing a lot of words,  but you expect your readers to supply the over all logic.

I suggest: write out the proof as an outline.  "I will show A, B, C and that's enough to establish the result because..." then prove A, B,C.

May be worth noting: the desired claim is nearly trivial.  Try to argue that,  if $R$ is a sub relation of an equivalence relation $S$ then the various completions of $R$ all sit inside $S$.

@lulu I'll rewrite it ASAP. I was a bit afraid that it would be harder than it seemed and was looking for some sanity check. They wrote a lot of stuff in the hint, I was like: "Damn, this must be way more complicated than it seems to be".
